# Поиск во всех классах пакета метода и передача аргументов

Tags: java, рефлексия

Реально ли написать код(я думаю используя reflection), который будет в пакете `A` искать классы `a,b,c` и в них находить методы(имя у методов одинаковое, но разные параметры), и вызывать их?

Comment: Да, через рефлексию реально

Comment: да, реально. но смысла не вижу.

Comment: Это реализуется через говнокод?

Comment: Да...это реально. Spring именно так и работает изнутри. Можно и методы и их аргументы достать через рефлексию

Comment: Но для обычных целей это не приветствуется, можно только с аннотациями поиграться и то не переусердствуя

Comment: @Евгений не говнокод, но надо учитывать что рефлексия очень медленная и что она нивелирует основные достоинства языка Java, делая программу менее устойчивой к рантайм-ошибкам. Её стоит избегать без крайней нужды.

Comment: Дайте больше контекста, возможно тут [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/5577).